# cloudinary javascript image uploads a blank file

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

i am using javascript to upload an image using the unsigned mode. the resultant image is a blank image or i can say an image filled with black color. not sure what is wrong. the code looks like follow:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/mycloud/image/upload", false);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    alert(xhttp.responseText);
  } else {
    alert("Error dude: " + xhttp.statusText);
  }
}

var parameters = {
  "file": imgData,
  "upload_preset": "mycode"
};

xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
```

resultant image is:

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/viksphotography/image/upload/v1490752341/irgvt7b3qwoug1vz7own.jpg
```

Please note that imgData is  base64 encoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use FormData for uploading the file:

```
const cloudName = 'your cloud name';
const unsignedUploadPreset = 'your unsigned upload preset';

// Upload base64 encoded file to Cloudinary
uploadFile('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhSAFIAf....');

// *********** Upload file to Cloudinary ******************** //
function uploadFile(file) {
  var url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/upload`;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var fd = new FormData();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      // File uploaded successfully
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      // https://res.cloudinary.com/cloudName/image/upload/v1483481128/public_id.jpg
      var url = response.secure_url;
      // Create a thumbnail of the uploaded image, with 150px width
      var tokens = url.split('/');
      tokens.splice(-2, 0, 'w_150,c_scale');
      var img = new Image(); // HTML5 Constructor
      img.src = tokens.join('/');
      img.alt = response.public_id;      
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
  };

  fd.append('upload_preset', unsignedUploadPreset);
  fd.append('tags', 'browser_upload'); // Optional - add tag for image admin in Cloudinary
  fd.append('file', file);
  xhr.send(fd);
}
```

See full example [here](http://codepen.io/eitanp461/pen/aJReEW). It will upload a small Michael Jordan jumpman image to your account.